# TYPO3 - Complex fluid condition f:if not working in 8.7

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

I tried a complex f:if condition in 8.7 like described here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/If.html

... but all my attempts failed (not working):

```
<h3 class="record-title" id="title"><f:if condition="{record.type}!='medium' || {record.type}!='large'">{record.firstname} - </f:if>{record.name}</h3>
<h3 class="record-title" id="title"><f:if condition="{0:record.type,1:record.type}!={0:medium,1:large}">{record.firstname} - </f:if>{record.name}</h3>
<h3 class="record-title" id="title"><f:if condition="{0:record.type,1:record.type}!={0:'medium',1:'large'}">{record.firstname} - </f:if>{record.name}</h3>
```

... instead I need to do this (working):

```
<h3 class="record-title" id="title">
    <f:if condition="{record.type}!='medium'">
        <f:if condition="{record.type}!='large'">
            {record.firstname} - 
        </f:if>
    </f:if>
    {record.name}
</h3>
```

Why is it not working as described? I'm working with 8.7.16 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first condition works correctly but it is not equal with the example which works for you, as in example nested `<f:if>` works like `&&` while your first condition uses `||`.

In second condition there are missing quotes.

Third will always return `true`, because you compare something like `['X', 'X']` to `['medium', 'large']`. If `X == 'medium'` then `X != 'large'` - there is no other way.

To make it work you just need to change `||` to `&&` in your first condition.

```
<h3 class="record-title" id="title">
    <f:if condition="{record.type}!='medium' && {record.type}!='large'">{record.firstname} - </f:if>
    {record.name}
</h3>
```